# How to mount a volume from Kubernetes on a Windows host to a Linux pod

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, volumes

I am trying to mount a volume within a Kubernetes pod (running linux) to a host folder on Windows 10. The pod starts up without issue, however, the data in the volumes aren't being reflected within the Pod and data set in the Pod isn't being reflected on the Windows host.

Here is my persistent volume:

```yaml
    kind: PersistentVolume 
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: "elastic-search-persistence"
      labels:
        volume: persistence
    spec:
      storageClassName: hostpath
      capacity:
        storage: 5Gi
      accessmodes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      hostPath:
        path: /c/temp/es
```

Here is my persistent claim:

```yaml
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: "elastic-search-persistence-claim"
    spec:
      storageClassName: hostpath
      volumeName: "elastic-search-persistence"
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

And here is my Pod using the above persistent volumes...

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: windows-volume-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: windows-volume-demo
        image: busybox
        command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: windows-volume-data-storage
            mountPath: /data/demo
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      volumes:
        - name: windows-volume-data-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: elastic-search-persistence-claim
```

I can start everything fine, however, when I create a file in my `C:\temp\es` folder on my Windows host, that file doesn't show inside the `/data/demo` folder in the Pod. And the reverse is also true. When I exec into the Pod and create a file in the `/data/demo` folder, it doesn't show in the `C:\temp\es` folder on the Windows host.

The folder/file privileges are wide open for the `C:\temp` folder and the `C:\temp\es` folder. I also tried exec-ing into the Pod and changing the write privs for the `/data/demo` folder to wide open -- all with no success.

This configuration works as expected on a Mac host (changing the volume paths for the host to a Mac folder). I suspect it is a privilege/permissions issue for Windows, but I am at a loss as to how to find/fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know which node in the cluster the pod will run on?  If it gets destroyed and recreated on a different node, the host-path content might not be there.  Depending on what exactly you're trying to store in the volume, a different volume type might be more appropriate.

Comment: I agree with you for a production environment. This example is running on my local machine with only one node in the cluster... the host-path should always be there.

Comment: Could you try with `/host_mnt/c/temp/es` instead of `/c/temp/es` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59876#issuecomment-628955935)?

Comment: I tried using /host_mnt/c/temp/es and it didn't work. It behaves as described in that it starts, but does not share the volume data.

Comment: @dgestep You use docker for desktop or wsl?

Comment: I'm using docker for desktop.

Comment: One other note to point out... I'm only using the hostpath persistent volume to allow my application to be demoed by the customer on their Windows laptop. The actual production environment will not use a hostpath persistent volume and will not be on Windows. With that said, if someone has an alternative approach to demo the application on Windows without using hostpath, I'd be open to that too.

Comment: Do you have `Use the wsl 2 based engine` enabled or disabled? You can check it in your general docker desktop [settings](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#general). If it's enabled then the answer which should work is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812948/volume-mounts-not-working-kubernetes-and-wsl-2-and-docker).