# Kubernetes how to correctly mount windows path in wsl2 backed environment

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a local image that runs fine this way:
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -v C:\Users\moritz\Downloads\1\imageService\examples1:/images -v C:\Users\moritz\entwicklung\projekte\imageCluster\logs:/logs imageservice`

Now i want this to run as Kubernetes (using built in from Docker-for-Windows v1.19.7) deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: image-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: image-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: image-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: image-service
        image: "imageservice"
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.9"
            memory: "1Gi"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /images
            name: image-volume
          - mountPath: /logs
            name: log-volume  
      volumes:
        - name: image-volume
          hostPath:
            path: "c:\\Users\\moritz\\Downloads\\1\\imageService\\examples1"
            type: Directory
        - name: log-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/c/Users/moritz/entwicklung/projekte/imageCluster/logs
            type: Directory
```

As you see i tried different ways to set up my host path on windows machine but i always get:

```
  Warning  FailedMount  0s (x4 over 4s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "log-volume" : hostPath type check failed: /mnt/c/Users/moritz/entwicklung/projekte/imageCluster/logs is not a directory
  Warning  FailedMount  0s (x4 over 4s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "image-volume" : hostPath type check failed: c:\Users\moritz\Downloads\1\imageService\examples1 is not a directory
```

I also tried other variants (for both):

- C:\Users\moritz\entwicklung\projekte\imageCluster\logs
- C:/Users/moritz/entwicklung/projekte/imageCluster/logs

So how to correctly setup these windows host path. (The next step would be to set them as environment variable.)

**Little update:**

removing `type: Directory` helps to **get rid of the error** and pod is starting but the mounts are not working. If i "look" into container in `/images` i don't see the images i have on my host and i don't see any logs in log mount while in container /logs contains the expected files.

in meantime i also tried (no avail)

- /host_mnt/c/...
- /C/Users/...
- //C/Users/...

Comment: edited my question - using built in Kubernetes from Docker for Windows

Comment: Hey @dermoritz, have you tried with that [path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63524931/11977760) also? From what I see there are new comments and people are saying it's working for them.

Comment: @Jakub this it is! thanks - make it an answer and get points :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812948/volume-mounts-not-working-kubernetes-and-wsl-2-and-docker/63524931#63524931), you can use below hostPath to make it work on wsl2.

```
// C:\someDir\volumeDir
hostPath:
  path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/someDir/volumeDir
  type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

There is also an example you can use.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-localpc
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-webserver
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && sleep 600"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/aaa
      name: mydir
    - mountPath: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/aaa/1.txt
      name: myfile
  volumes:
  - name: mydir
    hostPath:
      # Ensure the file directory is created.
      path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/aaa
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
  - name: myfile
    hostPath:
      path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/aaa/1.txt
      type: FileOrCreate
```