# Minikube, WSL2, Windows 11, No Docker Desktop - Unable to create persistent Volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have seen other posts on a similar topic, such as [Kubernetes how to correctly mount windows path in wsl2 backed environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985465/kubernetes-how-to-correctly-mount-windows-path-in-wsl2-backed-environment) but I cannot get a persistentVolume to work.

I am running a Windows 11 machine, WSL2. I have Ubuntu running inside WSL2, with docker, minikube and kubectl all installed. I do NOT have Docker for Windows Desktop installed as it now requires a license for commercial use.

When I look in the /run folder, I do not have a desktop folder so the paths given in all the articles I have found do not work. I get no errors when creating the pv and pvc and it says it is bound, but no files show up although I can see files in the corresponding folder inside the pod.

Is there some different workaround when you do not have Docker Desktop installed?

Answer (score 0):

Alan, I have a similar setup: Ubuntu, docker, minikube installed inside WSL2, and no Docker Desktop, but on Windows 10 machine.

- And I can mount windows dirs using this command:

```sh
minikube mount /mnt/c/Users/your_user:/host
```

This mounts your windows host dir c:/Users/your_user to /host dir inside minikube node.

- Or you can do this by running this command before creating a new minikube cluster:

```sh
minikube start --mount-string /mnt/c/Users/your_user:/host --mount
```

You can find more `minikube mount` options [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/mount/).

Let me know if this works on Windows 11, please.