# How to mount a host volume in Kubernetes running on Docker Desktop (Windows 10) backed by WSL2?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I've figured out the syntax to mount a volume (Kubernetes YAML):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: php
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/db_backups
          name: db-backups
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /mnt/c/Users/Mark/PhpstormProjects/proj/db_backups
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
      name: db-backups
```

And the volume does show when I drop into a shell:

```
kubectl --context docker-desktop exec --stdin --tty deploy/app-deployment-development -cphp -nmyns -- /bin/bash
```

But the `db_backups` directory is empty, so I guess the volume is backed by nothing -- it's not finding the volume on my Windows host machine.

I've tried setting the host path like `C:\Users\Mark\PhpstormProjects\proj\db_backups` but if I do that then my Deployment fails with a `CreateContainerError`:

> Error: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\Mark\PhpstormProjects\proj\db_backups:/app/db_backups:ro'

So I guess it doesn't like the Windows-style filepath.

So what then? If neither style of path works, how do I get it to mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985465/kubernetes-how-to-correctly-mount-windows-path-in-wsl2-backed-environment) it is clear that, for **WSL2** we need to mention the specific path before we are actually giving the path we desired in the host machine.

In your file you are giving like `path: /mnt/c/Users/Mark/PhpstormProjects/proj/db_backups` but you need to mention the path like this `path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/path_of_directory_in_local_machine`. The key is we need to mention `/run/desktop/mnt/host/` before we are going to give the actual path to the directory.

You gave the `type: DirectoryOrCreate` in the above file, so that is creating an **empty directory** in the path you mentioned. Because it is not actually going to your desired path.

So try with this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: php
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/db_backups
          name: db-backups
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/Mark/PhpstormProjects/proj/db_backups
#In my case tested with path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/d/K8-files/voldir
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
      name: db-backups
```

It worked in our case, we created a directory in **'d'** drive so we used this `path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/d/K8-files/voldir`. So try giving `/run/desktop/mnt/host/` before the actual path.

For more information refer this [Link](https://devpress.csdn.net/k8s/62ebfca589d9027116a0fe82.html)