# How to create the deployment, statefulset of service-registry(eureka-server) in kubernetes?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

I have been trying to create a statefulset of service-registry (eureka-server) in a springboot application. The reason i am doing this because i want to attach pre-defined name to the service-registry pod so that its able to communicate with all the eureka clients even after it restarts. Even though i have been able to create the services (headless and nodeport) with the configuration, but it doesn't create the pod/deployment and the PersistentVolumeClaim itself. Please check the below deployment yaml and suggest the changes.

```
# Define a 'Persistent Volume Claim'(PVC) for Storage, dynamically provisioned by cluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: service-registry-pv-claim # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce   #This specifies the mode of the claim that we are trying to create.
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi    #This will tell kubernetes about the amount of space we are trying to claim.


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka-cm
data:
  eureka_service_address: http://eureka-0.eureka:8761/eureka

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      name: eureka
  selector:
    app: eureka

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka
spec:
  serviceName: "eureka"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eureka
          image: my-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8761
          env:
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address
          volumeMounts: # Mounting volume obtained from Persistent Volume Claim
            - name: service-registry-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/eureka #This is the path in the container on which the mounting will take place.
      volumes:
        - name: service-registry-persistent-storage # Obtaining 'volume' from PVC
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: service-registry-pv-claim

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka-lb
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  selector:
    app: eureka
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8761
```

and below is the application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: "${HOSTNAME}.eureka"
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS}
```

this is how the eureka client apps are referring to eureka server

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    hostname: eureka-0
```

I am new to Kubernetes, so please suggest the changes.

Configuration after adding the PesistentVolume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: my-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostpath:
    path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/User/Documents/kubernetesbkp

---
# Define a 'Persistent Volume Claim'(PVC) for Storage, dynamically provisioned by cluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: service-registry-pv-claim # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce   #This specifies the mode of the claim that we are trying to create.
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi    #This will tell kubernetes about the amount of space we are trying to claim.


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka-cm
data:
  eureka_service_address: http://eureka-0.eureka:8761/eureka

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      name: eureka
  selector:
    app: eureka

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka
spec:
  serviceName: "eureka"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eureka
          image: my-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8761
          env:
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address
          volumeMounts: # Mounting volume obtained from Persistent Volume Claim
            - name: service-registry-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/eureka #This is the path in the container on which the mounting will take place.
      volumes:
        - name: service-registry-persistent-storage # Obtaining 'volume' from PVC
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: service-registry-pv-claim

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: rtb
  name: eureka-lb
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  selector:
    app: eureka
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8761
```

Comment: Hi @mamoon do you mean you are not able to see the pods and volumes? Can you try giving `$kubectl get statefulset`

Comment: Hi @DharaniDharGolladasari, yes neither pod nor volume is getting created. Initially, i tried without the pvc because i only require the name of the pod for it to be used in other microservices as i don't want the name to be changed. Can you suggest something. Thanks!

Comment: There is some cascading involved here so, if the PV is not created, anything trying to use it will not be created either. Do you get anything from `$ kubectl get pvc`? Also nice to know what kind of environment you are using for kubernetes cluster (Cloud, local, ...)?

Comment: Hi @grekier, no pvc isn’t there. I am trying it on local. Any suggestions you can give. Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to run kubernetes locally?

Comment: @grekier, I am using minikube

Comment: Suggested answer should work but there are pitfalls in minikube around the path you choose. Check https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the below deployment configuration which worked for me, but just one thing, i applied all of the configurations one by one, otherwise it doesn't work on a single apply and the statefulset isn't created then. Also, i am mentioning it as a single configuration file here for convenience.

Would be helpful if someone can point out why it doesn't work in a single apply command. Thanks!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: eureka-cm
data:
  eureka_service_address: http://eureka-0.eureka:8761/eureka

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eureka
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      name: eureka
  selector:
    app: eureka

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: eureka
spec:
  serviceName: "eureka"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eureka
          image: my-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8761
          env:
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eureka-lb
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  selector:
    app: eureka
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8761
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kubernetes locally then first you have to create a `PersistentVolume`. Only then you can use the **PersistentVolumeClaim** to retrive the storage from the **PV** you created. Otherwise your PVC claim will be in a **pending** state. Because without PV the PersistentVolumeClaim did not know that from where it needs to pick up the volume.

So try creating the PersistentVolume like this

PersistentVolume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostpath:
    path: /tmp/         #Path where you want to allocate your PV in local
```

Now you can create the PVC and statefulset as per your requirement.

**NOTE: Make Sure the PV storage is always greater or equal to the claim.**

If you are using the docker dekstop kubernetes then hostpath will be different than mentioned above, refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75306198) for it.

For more detailed information. Refer these links [link1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/kubernetes/kubernetes_volumes.htm) [link2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reserving-a-persistentvolume)

Comment: I will go through your suggestion and let you know. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: i tried with the above configuration, but still pv,pvc and statefulset not getting created @Dharani

Comment: Hi @mamoon when you run `kubectl get pv,pvc` what is the output you are getting ?

Comment: Hi @Durani, no output at all, only service gets created

Comment: Did you find any solution or still having the same issue?